# how to use Queue.java in another class

Tags: java, queue

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Queue <T>{
    private T[] QueueArr;
    private int front; 
    private int back;
    private int size; 

    public Queue(){}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Queue (int size)
    { 
        if (size <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be less than or equal to 0!");
        this.size = size;
        QueueArr = (T[]) new Object[size];
        front = -1;
        back = -1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty ()
    {
        if (front == -1 &&back == -1)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
    return (back +1) % size == front;
    }

    public void enQueue ( T ele)
    {
        if (isFull())
            throw new IllegalStateException ("The Queue is full!");
        else if (isEmpty())
        {
            front++;
            back++;
        }
        else
        {
            back +=1;
        }
        QueueArr[back] = ele;
    }

    public void deQueue()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't dequeue an empty queue!");
        else if (front == back)
        {
            front =-1;
            back = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            front = (front + 1) % size;
        }
    }   
    public T Front()
    {
        if(front == -1)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't return from an empty queue!");
        }                   
        return QueueArr[front];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("front is " + front + ", back is " + back +", size is " + size + "Queue is " + Arrays.toString(QueueArr));
    }   
}
```

I have implemented Queue data structure using circular array algorithm, I'm trying to implement this Queue class in another class.

For example: public class Inventory{}

would it be something like this:

```
public class Inventory extends Queue{}
```

I do get warning "Queue is a raw type. References to generic type Queue should be parameterized" when I do the line above.

I'm a beginner in Java.Thank for helping.

Comment: First you need to ask yourself, [is Inventoty a queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) or does [inventory has a queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)? One this is understood, you will know if Inventory needs to extend Queue, or has a field whom type is Queue

Comment: to answer this question, I wanted to enqueue item from the inventory in a FIFO manner, so I guess the Inventory should be a queue itself, in another word, the Queue Inventory contain the list of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reusing a class, you need to ask yourself, [is Inventoty a queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) or does [inventory has a queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)? One this is understood, you will know if Inventory needs to extend Queue, or has a field whom type is Queue.

Some questions you need to ask yourself for answering the question:

1. Do you want to use all queue's methods on Inventory, including `front()`, `enqueue()`, and `dequeue()`?
2. Do you want to be later able to reuse `Inventory` to support data which is not `Queue` (maybe `Stack`?) - has-a relationship is generally easier to refactor.
3. Do you want to be able to pass `Inventory` to a method that accepts `Queue` as an argument?

---

If Inventory is  a Queue (which I do not believe is what you want), you indeed need to extend it:

```
public class Inventory <T> extends Queue<T>{}
```

Or if Inventory has only one type of elements in the queue (Let this be `Item`):

```
public class Inventory extends Queue<Item>{}
```

However, if the more likely scenario, and Inventory has-a Queue, you need to allocate a field in Inventory, whom type is `Queue`:

```
public class Inventory <T> {
     private Queue<T> queue;
}
```

or again, if it has only one type of item:

```
public class Inventory {
     private Queue<Item> queue;
}
```

Comment: Thank, this is a very insightful answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Your `Queue` is a parameterized class. Java is warning you that a class that extends it (`Inventory`, in your case), should probably also be parameterized:

```
public class Inventory <T> extends Queue<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, IMO. Though it solves the warning, it does not teach the OP (who admits to being novice programmer) the basic fundementals of object design. Note that the question is not how to solve the warning, but how to reuse Queue